# Complement of XOR

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, xor

What is the most efficient algorithm for finding ~A XOR B? (Note that ~ is the complement function, done by reversing each 1 bit into 0 and each 0 into 1 bit, and XOR is the exclusive or function)

For example, ~4 XOR 6 = ~010 = 101 = 5 and ~6 XOR 9 = ~1111 = 0

Comment: I would say `~a ^ b`, probably.

Comment: See [the wiki on bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Comment: it's called xnor, but it's not usually one atomic operation in programming

Comment: The ~ function doesn't return the bit complement, however, as ~x=-x-1 in python

Comment: @Ben, how does that work in python?

Comment: @user3827695 It *is* the complement; Python uses two's complement binary.

Comment: That's just how's it's printed. If you use ~a ^ b, you will get the correct answer.   You see that because negative numbers are represented on modern computers in twos complement, where -x is /defined/ as ~x + 1

Comment: wait why is `6^9=1111` instead of `6^9=01111` or conversely why is `4^6=010` instead of just `10`?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, 6 is 110 and 9 is 1001, so we want 4 bitwise digits here.

Comment: Python doesn't print leading 0s. Conceptually they're there

Comment: @user3827695 Python uses an effectively-infinite amount of bits, per the article I've linked - if you want to use some fixed (or case-by-case) number of bits, you will need to write that yourself.

Comment: @Max, how would you find the positive complement of a number, for example ~16=0 and ~20=~(10100)=01011=11

Comment: @user3827695: AND it with the appropriate number of bits, e.g. `~16 & 0xf`. But `~16` is absolutely not `0`.

Comment: So how can my complement function be programmed? (change each 0 bit to 1 and each 1 bit to 0)

Comment: @user3827695 think about this - if you want the "positive complement" of e.g. `16` (`0b1111`), should that be `0` (`0b0000`)? `240` (`0b11110000`)? `1008` (`0b1111110000`)? How do you decide how many bits the starting number has? If your question is *"how can I write a function to do..."*, remember that **this isn't a code-writing service**.

Comment: Why are you so concerned with the intermediate representation? The end number? The bit width is completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an answer that takes into account the number of bits needed to store your integers:

```
def xnor(a, b):
    length = max(a.bit_length(), b.bit_length())
    return (~a ^ b) & ((1 << length) - 1)
```

I can't think of a situation where this is better than just `~a ^ b` however.  And it almost certainly makes no sense for negative numbers.

Comment: The number of bits needed to store `a`.  Seems to have been added in Python 2.7

Comment: ahh that explains it py2.6 here

Comment: Where do you find `bit_length`? Edit: never mind, it appears to be a built-in method on integers.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I rolled back your edit because there are numerical issues with things like `int(log(x))` (try `log((1 << 62) - 1, 2)` for example, it gives `62.00000000000001` but the answer should be less than `62`).  @MarkRansom's method is much better than that if you don't have `bit_length()`.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean the log method returns the same number of bits as the number returned by @MarkRansom's mask method ... both return 63 bits .... (that said suprisingly MarkRansom's answer looks significantly faster than the log method ... )

Comment: @JoranBeasley The log method will be wrong for some large numbers, starting at `2**48 - 1` it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem here is that `~` returns a negative number for a positive input, and you want a positive result limited to the significant bits represented in the inputs.

Here's a function that can generate a mask of bits that are needed in the result:

```
def mask(n):
    n = abs(n)
    shift = 1
    while n & (n + 1) != 0:
        n |= n >> shift
        shift *= 2
    return n
```

And here's how to use it:

```
print (~a ^ b) & mask(a | b)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use ==.

A XNOR B is same as == operator because:

A B NXOR 
F F T
F T F
T F F
T T T

Comment: This is true for booleans, but not for bitwise operators. There's no bitwise ==.

Comment: I would use ~A ^ B, then. There is no other options.